# Sent an extra field to serializers -DRF

Tags: python, django, database, django-rest-framework

I have a ModelSerializer with fields from the table SubscriptionsPlans.

serializer.py

```
class SubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model = SubscriptionsPlans
        fields = {
            'id',
            'name',
            'plan_type',
            'plan_details',
            'price'
        }
```

I want to sent an extra field name `sub_id` into this serializer from views. This sub_id will be True or False depending on a table `SubscriptionsOrder`. If SubscriptionsOrder has rows then the sub_id will be a True else False. SubscriptionsOrder for a specific user is looked here.

views.py

```
class SubscriptionView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        get_sub_id = SubscriptionsOrder.objects.filter(id=request.user).first()
        sub_id = get_sub_id.plan_selected
        subscription_details = SubscriptionsPlans.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)
        user_serializer = SubscriptionSerializer(subscription_details)
        return Response(user_serializer.data)
```

I want to sent sub_id along with the user_serializer.

models.py

```
class SubscriptionsPlans(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    plan_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    plan_details = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    request_per_month = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Subscription Plans'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Subscription Plans'


class SubscriptionsOrder(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(
        AppUser,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    plan_selected = models.ForeignKey(SubscriptionsPlans, null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    billing_info = models.IntegerField()
    payment_info = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Subscription Order'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Subscription Order'
```

before sending sub_id the output looks like this

```
     {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Professional",
        "plan_type": "MONTHLY",
        "plan_details": "{'Details'}",
        "price": 50.0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Business",
        "plan_type": "MONTHLY",
        "plan_details": "{Business}",
        "price": 100.0
    }
```

After sending sub_id

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Professional",
        "plan_type": "MONTHLY",
        "plan_details": "{'Details'}",
        "price": 50.0,
        "sub_id": True
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Business",
        "plan_type": "MONTHLY",
        "plan_details": "{Business}",
        "price": 100.0,
        "sub_id":False
    }
```

Comment: You can use Exists subquery to annotate `sub_id` field, see details here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries

Comment: This link doesn't answer my question. The value of `sub_id` depends on a different table.